# Can Windows 8.1 (Not RT) Tablets Run ADO.net Applications using SQL

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, windows-8.1, tablet

Is it possible that Windows 8.1 (Full, Not RT) Tablets, such as the Microsoft Surface 3, be able to run ADO.net desktop applications that are connected to a SQL database.

If so would the ADO.net application require extra code for touchscreen (i.e. on touching a button do this) or does the tablet handle the interaction automatically?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: They can run all the same applications as a desktop PC

Comment: It will all "just work".